# How to limit enter key press to only one button in a form having two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, form-submit

I have an HTML `form` having two submit type input buttons with different actions attached. The form should get submitted on click of any of these buttons. But on **enter key press**, **button-B** should trigger the submit. Now as i have **button-A** on top of **button-B** in the order, **button-A** is getting triggered on enter press.

Please note that changing the order of buttons is not possible in my case.

My code goes like this,

```
<form method="POST" action="someAction">
  <input type="text" name="fName"/>
  <input type="text" name="lName"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Action-A" name="button-A"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Action-B" name="button-B"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Is any real reason to have two submit buttons within one form?

Comment: @hindmost actually these buttons are attached with two different handlers in jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add listeners to all inputs and when the user hit enter you can prevent the default action by using `e.preventDefault()`. Then select the second submit button and click it.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //Select all of input in #form1 of type text
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 > input[type=text]");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        //Add listeners
        inputs[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            //Check if enter is pressed
            if(key == 13) {
                //Prevent from submitting with A
                e.preventDefault();
                //Click B
                document.getElementById('b').click();
            }
        }, false);
    }
}
</script>

<form id="form1" method="POST" action="someAction">
<input type="text" name="fName"/>
<input type="text" name="lName"/>
<input type="submit" value="Action-A" name="button-A"/>
<input type="submit" value="Action-B" id="b" name="button-B"/>
</form>
```